# Using Eclipse on Mac OS X, I get random invisible character \160 . Why?

Tags: character

I'm using Eclipse on Mac OS X and I randomly get character \160 (whatever that is) instead of a whitespace in my code.

From time to time when I compile I get this error:

```
java:74: illegal character: \160

if (c == '*' ||?c == '/')
```

when my code in Eclipse actually looks like:

`if (c == '*' || c == '/')`

This is annoying and usually resolved by deleting the supposed invisible `?` and pressing the <kbd>space bar</kbd> once again in the editor.

Why does this happen?

Comment: In this case, the stray error, 160, appears to be in decimal.

Comment: This is a duplicate. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)*

Comment: Decimal 160 (octal 240. hexadecimal 0xA0) could be CE/CP-1250, corresponding to U+00A0  [NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=156&number=128). UTF-8 U+00A0 is a two-byte sequence, 194 160 (decimal) → 0xC2 0xA0 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+00A0 (NO-BREAK SPACE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Hanynowsky mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697005/using-eclipse-on-mac-osx-i-get-random-invisible-character-160-why/10957618#10957618), it is related to a different encoding between the source you copied and the one from your file. I have not found any way to automatically remove the bogus mismatching characters, but you can actually see them in Eclipse if you enable the editor to show whitespaces.

For doing that:

- set Eclipse to "show whitespace characters" (option under *Preferences* → *General* → *Editors* → *Text Editors*)
- the bogus \160 character will appear as " ." even if your other spaces will appear as ".". So you just need to delete the " ." occurrences and you are good!

Answer (score 2):

When you copy / paste a code from a website page into your IDE editor, you might get this error as the copied code has invisible unknown characters, usually white spaces.
Unfortunately I do not know of any solution bar to remove and re-ident every white spaces between your code's identifiers.