# I am getting the error 'stray '\160' in program ' for my program

Tags: c, arrays

I am getting the error 'stray '\160' in program ' for my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    int x[500], n, my_numb, j, found;

    do {
        printf("Enter n < 10\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    } while ((n < 1) || (n > 10));
}
```

I am unable to post entire program, but part of my program is as above.

Comment: I don't suppose this is the part where the error is reported? care to mark **the line** where this happens? The only error(s) I immediately see in the above code is an invalid `void` return type for `main()` and no closing curly.

Comment: Unless you're on an embedded platform, void main() is invalid C.  It should be int main(void) or int main(int argc, char *argv[]) most likely.  It would be nice if you could post a compilable example that reproduces the bug.

Comment: Is it possible you have an erroneous unicode character in your program?

Comment: Are you using Dev-C++ by any chance? If so, this error can occur if you copy and paste code into the editor. Along the lines of what @Patashu said.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697005/using-eclipse-on-mac-i-get-random-invisible-character-160-why which has the answer you need :)

Comment: Yes. I am using Dev C++ and copied the code from a slide in Online Training Program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using eclipse on Mac OSX, I get random invisible character \160 . Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697005/using-eclipse-on-mac-osx-i-get-random-invisible-character-160-why)

Comment: In this case, the stray error, 160, appears to be in decimal.

Comment: This is a duplicate. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you have a stray control code in your source file?  Are you using an editor that shows unprintable characters, or Unicode embedded in the file?  I made a few changes to your program, and this compiles cleanly here. And runs without error.  Also changed the logic in the while loop slightly so it matches what is being asked for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int x[500], n, my_numb, j, found;

   do {
      printf("Enter 0 < n < 10\n");
      scanf(" %d", &n);
   } while ((n < 1) || (n >= 10));
   return 0;
}
```

If you copy this into a new file on your own system, do you still see the error message?  I suspect you have corrupted it, or accidentally embedded a control sequence of some sort in your original program.

Comment: Yes. I am using Dev C++ and copied the code from a slide in Online Training Program. May be the error was due to copying. When I copied the code you posted I got no error!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  If you chosen editor has an option to allow you to make such characters show up clearly when you are working on them, it could avoid this happening again in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you found [one of these](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm). It's a non-breaking space.  If you copied the code from a website, for instance, this would correspond to &nbsp;.  Unfortunately it's difficult to see it since it's a unicode whitespace. If you happen to be on a *nix system, try viewing the file with `cat -vte`.

Comment: Yes. I am using Dev C++ and copied the code from a slide in Online Training Program.

Comment: Re *"it's difficult to see it since it's a Unicode whitespace"*: If it is UTF-8 (194 160 (decimal) → 0xC2 0xA0 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+00A0 ([NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=156&number=128))), it can searched for in most modern text editors using the regular expression `\x{00A0}` (in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) and others the notation is different, `\u00A0`). I am not sure if it will work for CE/CP-1250 (a single 160 (decimal)).